# Motor shield for Arduino Nano ATmega328

Tags: arduino-nano, atmega328, arduino-motor-shield

I am looking for a cheap and not so space consuming motor shield for my Arduino Nano ATmega328. I would like to charge the whole thing with a 9V battery. The shield must have at least 2.1A of output current so I can run 3 brushed DC motors on it. There will also have to be some pins left for a Bluetooth card and 3 analog pins for sensors.

Do you know any shields that meet my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:**

Nano + Shield = no possible

---

> [...] 9V battery. The shield must have at least 2.1A of output [...]

You can't invent power out of nowhere.

---

**Options for the shield**

**Option 1:**

Use an other Arduino. It will simplify everything.

**Option 2:**

Use a Nano to Uno adapter.

**Option 3:**

By an Uno shield and connect it pin by pin to the Nano.

**Option 4:**

Use MOSFETs. They'll work fine for what you are trying to do.

---

**Options for powering**

**Option 1:**

Use a 2s lipo. Voltage is above 5V so you have to reduce it with a down converter, but you should have enough juice for the motors.

**Option 2:**

Use a *lot* of AA, some in series to augment the voltage and then in parallel to augment the current.

**Option 3: (just the the crazy minded)**

Use a lead-acid battery (aka car battery).

Comment: Is  there a way, when using MOSFETs to switch the direction of the motor's rotation?

Comment: H-bridge. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYafyPZ15g8

Comment: But why can't I use the regular 9V battery?

Comment: 9V doesn't have enough current.

Comment: What is its current?

Comment: Depends, but they are mostly below 500mAh

Comment: Doesn't that mean I can run all of them for just 0,2 hours?

Comment: If it doesn blow up because you draw too much current.

Comment: Ok, I will try the AA battery tehnique. Thank you btw